# Этимология слова "подоплека"

Tags: этимология

Насколько я знаю, первоначальное значение этого слова — подкладка у одежды. Потом оно стало употребляться в переносном значении: истинная, но скрытая причина. А интересно было бы узнать этимологию этого слова. "Подо-" — это, как я понимаю, приставка, а что тогда "-плека"?

Answer (score 6):

Плечо. Подоплёка изначально подклад у рубахи от плеч до половины спины и груди.

Answer (score 3):

Г.П.Цыганенко.Этимологический словарь русского языка......Из слова ПЛЕЧО в рус.яз.вследствие т.наз. ОБРАТНОГО ОБРАЗОВАНИЯ выделилось слово ПЛЕКО.Слово ПЛЕЧО со звуком Ч было принято как производное от мнимого ПЛЕКО при чередовании К/Ч(ср. аналогично образованное ПУГАТЬ от ПУЖАТЬ).Сущ. ПЛЕКО известно в диал.со знач. ПЛЕЧО.....ПОДОПЛЁКА-первоначально "подкладка.......", затем перен.-"действительная, но скрытая причина, основание чего-либо".В своем перен. знач.это слово вошло в рус. литерат. яз. во 2 полов. 19 века